# Cannot compile with API 18

Tags: android, api, android-studio

I have installed Android Studio 0.2.4 and the SDK for API 18 from http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r18-windows.exe.

Now, when I start a new project, I can choose `target SDK : API 18`, but I can only compile with API 17. What to I have to do in order to compile with API 18? 
[image: unable to choose higher than api 17]

Comment: is there any problem to change option?

Comment: @PankajKumar I've updated the image. As you can see, I am unable to choose any other versions than API 17 to compile with

Comment: Have you tried updating the Platform and/or Build tools. Since it allows API 18 for Target SDK I think the SDK is fine but maybe you need the latest "tools" in order to compile for it.

Comment: @free3dom I thought all of that was bundled in the studio, but no? I have tried updating everything from the packet manager but no luck.

Comment: Everything does come bundled, but the build/platform tools do get updated separately from the studio (via the SDK Manager). However, if that does not fix your problem, then it may be a bug in 0.2.4 - [there seems to be a lot of those in 0.2.4](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/5T2Re3Ve1Tx) :). Update 0.2.5 is out now so give that a go.

Comment: @free3dom I don't know why, but today API 18 showed in the SDK Manager. Thank you for solving this :)

Comment: No problem, glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating, make sure you have android-18 in your android-stuidio/sdk/platforms folder.  I had to copy mine from my Android folder where sdk manager downloads them on my pc.  After I did that, it made the dropdown with api-18 available.

Comment: If you read the comments on my Q you see I got it working. I think I just stumbled in to a bug of some sort. Probably should have closed this question...

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was previously using intelliJ 13 EAP and switched to Android Studio for better Gradle support. Android Studio was pointing to a different Android SDK than I was updating. Android Studio bundles an Android SDK and places it in "\(relevant Program Files)\Android\android-studio\sdk" for all users or "\Users\(username)\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk" for just me user. So in your case I don't think you needed to download the SDK separately and it would have defaulted to the bundled SDK. To check or switch Android SDKs in Android Studio:

- From the initial start screen choose "Configure/Project Defaults/Project Structure".
- Click on "Project Settings/SDKs" on the left.
- Check "Android SDK home path" points to the Android SDK you are using
  and update if necessary using "Apply" or "OK".
- Restart Android Studio and try create a new project.